# Many many css backgrounds performance

Tags: php, javascript, css, background-image, background-position

I am trying different methods to turn an image into divs that represent each pixel.

One method has been using php imagecolorat to create divs with a `background-color` which works well.

However what if I had **thousands** of divs `width:1px;height:1px;` each with the same css `background-image` with incremented background position?

What performance hit would this have? Ie: does the browser draw the entire image many times or only the section that is visible as the background? Note the original image is several hundred kb.

Thanks

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I am really curious why you want to do this.

Comment: Having thousands of dynamically generated div will most likely kill your page performances. specially if you want than to add some fancy *efx* to each "pixel"

Comment: @Justin I'll be happy to link to a site when I have something working.  I want to be able to manipulate the image on a pixel basis with javascript so that i can animate sweeping filters etc. Using the php approach has worked well so far and by using AJAX to load it in page load isn't two bad. Ideally I could make this client-side though

Comment: Ouch. Every mouse event object contains coordinates as well, there is absolutely no need for a horrifying mass of div elements.

Comment: Ha yeah its like 100,000 divs. Surprisingly performance isn't that bad. I want the images to be completely manipulatable. Ie, shuffle around pixels, change individual colors etc

Comment: You are killing your browser and you must have misunderstood something very wrong. Only because it's technically possible it must not mean it is practically useful. But if you really want to crush the browser, add a 10 MB background picture per each of those DIVs so that the background image actually is one. And maybe add some alpha blending while you are at it and animate it with javacsript. The real fun.

Comment: @hakre Ok no need to diss, its a genuine question. I want to be able to do complex animations on a pixel basis and was researching interesting ways to do this. I may just go for canvas/svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the section of the image should be drawn, however the drawing operation will be called as many times as the amount of pixels, so that will be a performance hit. Did you try writing any test code and measuring how it works?

Comment: Thanks, Do you think drawing one pixel of an image would be equivalent to drawing one pixel of `background-color`? . I haven't tested with background images yet, was wondering about the logistics first. But perhaps I will just go for it.

Comment: No, your browser is not a bitmap painting program. Better look into canvas support for that. It's quite fast.

Comment: Yeah canvas looks like the best method. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thousands of divs will hurt your performance no matter what, because the browser has to parse each div, add it to the DOM, then render it.

The actual performance will be different on different browsers.  Only the part of the image being requested will be drawn, but the rendering function that draws the image will be called for EVERY div.  It's more or less whether the specific browser's implementation can render one pixel of an image faster or parse a string and print the image.  If the browser has the image in-memory, the difference might be moot.  But if the browser has to open the image file every time, then the disk access will kill you.

That being said, I'm willing to bet there are better ways of doing what you are trying to do.  You can get the pixel the mouse clicked/hovered/etc using JavaScript, and then add an absolute div at that specific point to create the "filter" you are talking about. Furthermore, if two pixels next to each other get tagged, you can just expand the former div, rather than creating a new one, which will help the performance by a lot

In other words, look into just loading the image with an `img` tag, and then using JavaScript to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hm thats an interesting idea. I went with thousands of divs because I want the image to be destructible. Ie: explode then come back together with javascript animations. At the time I couldn't think of any way to slice up an <img> tag. What about using <canvas> to draw thousands of rectangles - one for each pixel?

Comment: Again, possible, but `<canvas>` support varies, and whenever you say "thousands of <whatever_html_objects>" you are going to deal with performance issues.  You should try to find ways to limit the number of objects that need to be created.  If you are just animating an explosion and redraw, look into generating a GIF image, and then keep it hidden, show the animation when you need to, etc.  Just another idea.  If you don't want a performance killer, you need to find ways to limit the number of objects you are using.